# Running PHP frontend site with node.js page connecting both together

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, socket.io, express.io

I have created a php site, doing the basic stuff reading from a sqlite database, logging in etc. This is currently running on xampp on port 80 and all is fine.

I have created another page which is ran on node.js it uses socket.io and express.io.
Currently running on port 8080.

I want to click on a link on the php site that directs me to the node.js page which are both on different ports.
I hope this is understandable, I have done alot of searching on the matter and cannot find a viable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080">Link</a>
```

If i am wrong please specify your Problem

Answer (score 0):

Change the link to include the port of the node server, like so:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/yourNodePage">Node Page</a>
```

If you want to go back from Node to PHP:

```
<a href="http://localhost/yourPHPPage">PHP Page</a>
```